# How to have different cursors on different bar groups of column chart in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

[image]

Here on the Total bars i want to have default cursor but on tires bars i want to have cursor: pointer.

Is there a way to do that programatically not using css? Because there can be 100s of column groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `cursor` style for points with a specific `x` value. For example:

```
chart.series.forEach(s => {
  s.points.forEach(point => {
    if (point.x === 1) {
      point.graphic.css({
        cursor: 'pointer'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vw06d5yL/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#css

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you use CSS?

```js
const colors = ['#648DE6', '#BBA8F6', '#19DCEA'];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        borderRadius: 8
      }
    },
    colors: colors,
    title: {
      text: 'Car Parts'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Total', 'Tires']
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Cost'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'One',
      data: [8, 9],
      color: colors[0]
    }, {
      name: 'Two',
      data: [1, 6],
      color: colors[1]
    }, {
      name: 'Three',
      data: [11, 5],
      color: colors[2]
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
.highcharts-series-group .highcharts-series .highcharts-point:nth-child(2) {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/10.3.3/css/highcharts.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/10.3.3/highcharts.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

If you want to make this dynamic, you could use JavaScript.

```js
const colors = ['#648DE6', '#BBA8F6', '#19DCEA'];

function setCursorForChart(chart, seriesLabel) {
  const categoryIndex = [...chart.container
      .querySelectorAll('.highcharts-xaxis-labels text')]
    .map(textEl => textEl.textContent).findIndex(text => text === seriesLabel);
    
  document.querySelectorAll('.highcharts-series-group .highcharts-series')
    .forEach((series) => {
      series.querySelectorAll('.highcharts-point')
        .forEach((point, index) => {
          if (index === categoryIndex) {
            point.style.cursor = 'pointer';
          }
        });
    })
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        borderRadius: 8
      }
    },
    colors: colors,
    title: {
      text: 'Car Parts'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['Total', 'Tires']
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Cost'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'One',
      data: [8, 9],
      color: colors[0]
    }, {
      name: 'Two',
      data: [1, 6],
      color: colors[1]
    }, {
      name: 'Three',
      data: [11, 5],
      color: colors[2]
    }]
  });

  setCursorForChart(chart, 'Tires'); // Pass in the chart ref
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/10.3.3/css/highcharts.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/10.3.3/highcharts.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: What if I have 20 col groups and the cursor is dependant on a value, if the value exists cursor should be pointer.

Comment: Ex: If value > 20 show pointer else default cursor. Something like that

Comment: @priyadarshikumar I added a JS example. You would need a full example including data and a description of what happens for each data point. No one can guess what you are intending as functionality.

Comment: @priyadarshikumar also, I added both a CSS and "programmatic" scenario for your given question. You never specified "value" in your title nor prompt.